# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I'm using Feed Importer to import data from a csv file, and I got this error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA0 a TN...' for column 'message' at row 1`

All values are in english characters, and I really don't know how to solve this problem

Help please. thanks

Answer (score 5):

What is the origin of your CSV file? Are you sure that it is properly encoded using UTF-8? This error is coming from an issue with the database handler trying to process non-UTF8 characters (see: http://drupal.org/node/1140194).

The particular character it is having problems according to your error above is the "&nsbp;" character or 0xC2 and 0xA0, you'' want to convert your file to UTF-8 or alternatively if you have control over what ever is generating your export, strip it out using php following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515394)

Comment: I tried opening it up in notepad and saved it in UTF-8, but it says the file it's unwritable when I import from the modified file.

Comment: You likely messed something up when you saved it out.  The encoding issue can be a real pain.  If you don't have the source encoding right, converting to UTF-8 won't do mush (it has to know what to convert *from*).  Very often, I just search/replace these bad characters with Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the error while using the db_insert then you can use the following code

```
$val = mb_check_encoding($val, 'UTF-8') ? $val : utf8_encode($val);
```

if it is just matter of one field value.